# Rails - Pluck name of a child record in the view(or helper)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a 3 level relationship.

User has_many Clients has_many Projects

`User.projects` will work `User.clients` will work.

Within the view I am trying to get a break down of the Projects, per Client, a user has.

IE Client A has 2 Projects, Client B has 4, Client C had 3. It'll return "Client A: 2. Client B: 4. Client C 3."

The closest I can get, presently, is `pie_chart current_user.projects.group(:client).count` which is actually just returning something along the lines of `#<Client:0x000000xd3948>` - the model/relation I assume.

I try to do `current_user.clients` and all records will return `undefined`.

I'm thinking perhaps I need to move this into a helper and iterate of `user.clients` and tally it up, but this seems wrong considering the relation.

(Unsure what other input to add)

Essentially I need a `Group By` but struggling on Rails-ing it.

`SELECT clients.name, count(*) FROM clients JOIN projects on clients.id = projects.client_id WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY clients.name;`

This query returns the exact results I need.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I ended up using a ERB -> JavaScript as I've done in the past.

1) I created a helper to generate the array. The format Google Charts wants is [Name, Count]

```
module ProjectsHelper
    def get_projects_per_client(user)
        custom_arr = []
        custom_arr << ['Client', 'Projects per Client']
        user.clients.each do |p|
            custom_arr << [p.name, p.projects.count]
        end
        return custom_arr
    end
end
```

I force prepended the header I needed, and then used a very simple call within the JavaScript - 
`var client_arr = <%= raw get_projects_per_client(current_user) %>`

The purpose of raw is to remote symbol/quote replacement. Other-wise your strings become `&quot;` and break the JavaScript.

Unsure if this is the proper way but I kind of enjoy it's impact.

Comment: try this `custom_arr = user.clients.collect { |p|  [p.name, p.projects.count] }`

Comment: @StephenM Much cleaner than mine - Thank you! I'll look into `collect`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do all of that in a single query like this:

```
user.projects
  .select("projects.name, COUNT(clients.id) AS clients_count")
  .left_joins(:clients)
  .group(:id)
  .map { |project| [project.name, project.clients_count] }
```

You could also add a counter cache for your projects -> clients relationship like this:

Migration:

```
class AddClientCounterCacheToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :clients_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
  end
end
```

Client model:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project, counter_cache: true
end
```

Then you can look up the count of clients for a project WITHOUT doing a N+1 like this:

```
project.clients.size
```

Its import you use `.size` and not `.count`, since `.count` will always execute another query against your database.

This would then end up looking like this:

```
user.projects.map { |project| [project.name, project.clients.size] }
```

Counter caching also saves resources when using code like `project.clients.any?`, `project.clients.empty?` and so on.

If you want to count the clients for a user, you can add a `has many through` relationship on your user model like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects
  has_many :clients, through: :projects
end
```

Then you can get the clients count like this:

```
user.clients.size
```